# provisional profile not showing in app validation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, itunes

I am working on an IOS application. I used to upload the build into the test flight for external testers in my organization. Now I want to upload it into iTunes. I have created an iTunes record as they mentioned in the documents. But when I validate the application I can't see the provisional profile. I again changed the profile in Xcode to the previous profile which I used to archive. But that's also not working now (not showing) please help me someone.

Comment: You have to make two different provisional profile for tester and app submission.For tester you have to added devices.and for app submission devices not required.you cant use tester provisional profile for app submission

Comment: yes i have created a distribution profile to build the app into test-flight too. it is used to work fine. when it comes to iTunes they said that there will be a profile starts with XC: . that also there in my apple account. but no any profile can be seeing in app validation when i tried to validate the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved the issue. i don't know what the reason was. but i open up a back up project and archived again. and that worked fine. and also i have found a tutorial regarding that.

[app distribution on iTunes Connect](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload it to itunesconnect with your developer provisioning profile, you would need Distribution profile to upload it on itunesconnect.[This](http://lessons.runrev.com/m/4069/l/32957-how-do-i-create-a-distribution-profile-for-ios) will help you to create distribution profile.

Comment: yes i have created a distribution profile to build the app into test-flight too. it is used to work fine. when it comes to iTunes they said that there will be a profile starts with XC: . that also there in my apple account. but no any profile can be seeing in app validation when i tried to validate the app